# How to match a string with the format "20959WC-01" in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to restrict a user to enter a value which is similar to the value "20959WC-01". I mean it must contains 5 integers followed by two character, a '-' and two integers.

Comment: guessing from the tag 'nsregularexpression'... the data to the server comes from an iOS application? Please clarify this

Comment: no it comes from a 3rd party API, it's not an IOS application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = '!
    ^                       # start of string
    \d{5}                   # five digits
    [[:alpha:]]{2}          # followed by two letters
    -                       # followed by a dash
    \d{2}                   # followed by two digits
    $                       # end of string
!x';
$matches = preg_match($pattern, $input);
```

Comment: whooo!! ,,,, you are just awesome, you saved my time man, thanks so much for your precious time and effort  :) +1 for you.....

Comment: hey! dude what to do if we have to do the same in jquery?

Comment: That would be more like webo80's answer (because you can't rely on:the character class alpha:): `if ( inputstring.match("/^[0-9]{5}$[A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/") ) ...` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: i have tried the above one in jquery, but it doesn't help, here is my code, ... if(!case_val.match("/^[0-9]{5}$[A-Za-z]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/")) {          i don't know what i am doing wrong here...

Comment: Better open another question with the javascript tag instead of php.

Comment: here is what i got: and it's working:                                                              /^[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}$[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/',$input);
```